# Trouble with ZFTool: Module (ZFTool) could not be initialized

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, fatal-error

[ZFTool](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool) is the maintenance tool for Zend Framework applications. There are several ways to [install](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/blob/master/README.md) it. I use it from a PHAR file.

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/lib/ZendFramework/zftool
$ cd /usr/lib/ZendFramework/zftool
$ wget http://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar
$ ln -s  /usr/lib/ZendFramework/zftool/zftool.phar /usr/bin/zf
$ chmod 755 /usr/bin/zf
```

It works, when I execute the tool outside of a ZF application. But now I tried this whithin an application and get this error:

```
root@devvm:/usr/lib/ZendFramework/test# cd /path/to/application/ root@devvm:/path/to/application# zf PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (ZFTool) could not be initialized.' in /path/to/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:175 Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(149): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#1 /path/to/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(90): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('ZFTool')
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#3 /path/to/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#4 /path/to/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php( in /path/to/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 175
```

Why does it happen? How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you need to install zftool into your project. user2900416 kind of hinted at this, but I think it is more correct to install zftool using composer like so for each project:

```
composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

This solved it for me. It is discussed in an issue here: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

Check the case of the module.php file:

Make sure your **M**odule.php file is written with a capital M otherwise the file may not be found. This took me a day to bug test so I really hope I save someone the same trouble!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. This is what I did to fix it with 2 steps:
(1) Download ZFTool zipball as suggested by manual installation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html.
(2) Unzip the zipball under your application's module/ directory with directory name as ZFTool/.

Then, the Module(ZFTool) has been installed in your application and can be initialized by either invoking 
"zftool.phar create module ModuleName" 
or
"zf.php create module ModuleName" where zf.php is in the zipball.

It looks REALLY stupid to copy the ZFTool module inside each application but I have spent days in trying to find a better one without any luck.n Hope someone can propose one.